# Getting two components to sit horizontally in react while using event object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the event object to try and create three images next to each other. I am running into an issue where because they are returned in order, they keep stacking vertically when I want them to be in two rows, with three items per row.

Here is my current code for App.js:

```
function App() {
  let imgGen = [{img:""},{img:""},{img:""},{img:""},{img:""},{img:""}];
  let images = imgGen.map((image1) => {
    return <GenSlide data={image1}/>
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Entry />
      {images}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my code for the GenSlide class:

```
function GenSlide (props) {
    return (
        <div class="imagePackage">
            <img alt="this image is busted" width="300px" src={props.data.image}/>
            <button id="theButton">Save</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: tried using `<span>` instead of `<div>` in `GenSlide` component?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the flexbox or grid layout to accomplish this.

By default a div is a block element which puts line breaks before and after each element. If you set them to inline-block there will still be spacing in between them.

For more info read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model